# How can I combine ENV statement in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As an exameple with the `RUN` statement, if my code is:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git
RUN apt-get clean
```

I can do:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git && apt-get clean
```

If my ENV is:

```
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB postgres
ENV POSTGRES_HOST db
```

How can I combine ENV statement in one line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example from the Dockerfile reference

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

```
ENV myName="John Doe" myDog=Rex\ The\ Dog \
    myCat=fluffy
```